# MongoDB - prevent index auto creation

Tags: mongodb, indexing, spring-data-mongodb

I write an application with MongoDB as database and I use Spring Data for MongoDB.

**My issue:**

I have two databases, as follow:

- tenant
- customer1

in `tenant` DB I have some collections to routing and in `customer1` I have collections about business logic.

I want to create collection named `SpreadingRuleType` with its indexes only in `customer1` database, but after application starts, I find that collection in `tenant` database too

**Context:**

I've a bean named `SpreadingRuleType` as follow:

```
@Document(collection = "SpreadingRuleType")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(def = "{'name' : 1, 'description': 1}")
})
public class SpreadingRuleType extends AbstractAuditEntity {
// body class

}
```

When my application up on MongoDB will be create collection with following indexes:

- *id*
- name_1_description_1

Class to perform this is `MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator` located in `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index` namespace.

How may I prevent index and collection auto creation in `tenant` database?

Comment: Remove the index definition from your entity and listen on the application initialization to create the index via Template API.

Comment: @mp911de: Yes, but I prefer works with annotation. If doesn't exist other solutions, I'll create by API

Comment: You should separate both the dbs while setting up the mongo configuration and provide base package for each. All the spring mongodb calls are made through db factory while using provided mapping context from configuration.